# UIButton draw layer in context makes it unclickable

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

I am creating a circular view by laying out buttons in a circle. When I draw my button using this line:

```
[button.layer renderInContext:ctx];
```

I am not able to click on the button, actions are not invoking. Is there any way to get the action working?

Also just tested, if I subclass UIButton and overwrite the hitTest:withEvent method, it is also not called.

Thanks

Comment: Apparently renderInContext just blits the snapshot of your button into the layer composition, so the button itself is not able to respond to any incoming touch events. Why not to work with UIButtons directly and reposition them accordingly?

Comment: ah right, I got the X and Y already, so I must not draw it :) thanks!